# cmake - preventing `make clean` from cleaning ExternalProject

Tags: build, makefile, cmake

I was wondering if there's some way to prevent `make clean` in cmake from re-building external dependencies. I'm using `ExternalProject` to build third party c++ libraries, and they do not have to be rebuilt even if I do `make clean`.

On the other hand, I might want to create a new rule, say, `make really-clean`, which even clears the dependencies. is there a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you use ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND, or ADD_LIBRARY or other ADD_* to create the dependency files.

If your `ExternalProject` has it's own directory and you can put `CMakeLists.txt` in that directory, you can easy put following in that `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM 1)
```

So those dependency files won't get cleaned.

If not, you may need to avoid to put the external dependencies as the output files.
For example, if you use

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT libdep
   COMMAND dep_gen_cmd
   ....
)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT prj
   ....
   DEPENDS libdep
)
```

then you need to change it to:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(libdep_gen
      COMMAND dep_gen_cmd
      ...
)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT prj
     COMMAND test -e libdep || make libdep_gen
     ...
)
```

Comment: As of now, that works only for Makefile Generators and not mine - ninja
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators